# Getting the GUID of the current user?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to add a user's GUID in with the information I retrieve from a user when they submit a post. How can I get the GUID?

I am using the default authentication system that comes along with an ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you are using the ASP.NET Membership provider:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
Guid guid = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
```

or simply:

```
Guid guid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

Comment: Also, `User.Identity.Name` isn't necessary. You can just use `(Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey`.

Comment: @Maxim Zaslavsky: True dat, I added it to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: My MVC project doesn't know what Membership is and no compiler directive is suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply use the username instead of hitting the database for something like this:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult PostComment()
{
    var username = User.Identity.Name;
    // Here you know the user trying to post a comment
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hmm my plan was to use the GUID as the foreign key. Is it better to use a user's username?

Comment: I would think that this might be a flaw in the membership library as usernames are something the user chose (thus something they'd want to change) and Guid lookups must be somehow optimized in SQL Server.

Comment: The username is *not* guaranteed unique or consistent over time. People change their names. Two people employed during different time periods could get the same username; they should *not* end up with a shared history.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there is a MVC use of the Membership example, with explanation in this [blog](http://mvctutorialsandguides.blogspot.co.nz/2012/04/aspnet-sql-membership-provider-how-to.html). It shows how you can get the membership information of current logged in user.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get the user guid from the user name:

```
Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser(user.Username).ProviderUserKey;
```