# How to get UserId which is uniqueidentifier

Tags: asp.net

I am coding in asp.net web forms . I have table with users generated from asp.net by default
I need to get current UserId  which in my case by default is uniqueidentifier

```
string user = User.Identity.Name; //this give me the name
            string name = TextBoxCategoryName.Text;
            this.connection.Open();
            command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "insert into ProfitCategories(name, IdUser/*this is foreign key to Users table*/) values ( '" + name + "', '"+user+"' )";
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            connection.Close();
```

Comment: Does this post answer your question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769313/getting-the-guid-of-the-current-user

Answer (score -1):

Try ExecuteScalar()  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx

Also, see this previous answer specific to returning a GUID:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/8398174/280785

Comment: Why are you using `SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)`? The question states that a uniqueidentifier is being used

Comment: You can't get uniqueidentifier with cast or something via executenonquery. just use upper select query ...