# How to get the GUID of the current user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, guid

I want to get the `Guid` of the current user.
Here is my code:

```
System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User;
String username = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("~/logtext.txt"), "username " +   username + Environment.NewLine);
if (username != "")
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
         MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(User.Identity.Name);
         if (user != null) 
         {
              //get the GUID
              Guid guid = (Guid)user.ProviderUserKey;
              System.IO.File.AppendAllText(Server.MapPath("~/logtext.txt"), "Authenticated: " + User.Identity.Name + Environment.NewLine);
         }
    }
}
```

The `MembershipUser` return null although the user is authenticated.
I also tried to use:

```
DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry();
//entry.Username = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
entry.Username = User.Identity.Name.ToString();
DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
searcher.Filter = "(objectclass=user)";
```

But it does not work without `entry.Password` (I don't have it).

Comment: Can't you use `User.Identity.GetUserId()`?

Comment: What's this entry.Password you are talking about? It's not in your code, and you state that it does not work without it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the GUID of the current user?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769313/getting-the-guid-of-the-current-user)

Comment: I can't see User.Identity.GetUserId().

Comment: The entry.Password is the password of the user

Comment: @o_s it is an extension method, so you need the right using directyive.

Comment: insert [`using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.aspnet.identity.identityextensions.getuserid%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) in the top of your file.

Comment: @Patrick the name space does not exist

Comment: I copied it verbatim from msdn, so it most definitely exists. Maybe you haven't included the correct dll (or nuget package) in your project.